# Getting an error in one signal push notification : contents must be key/value collections by language code

Tags: java, push-notification, onesignal

I'm trying to set as a simple message to the contents field in onesignal request body. And I'm getting an error message **"contents must be key/value collections by language code"**.

```
ObjectNode jsonMessage = Json.newObject();
jsonMessage.put("contents", "{\"en\": \"English Message\"");
```

> Push Response******** {"errors":["contents must be key/value collections by language code"]}

Comment: I have no idea of what onesignal is, but my guess is that it expects an object in contents, not a string

Comment: Not very sure about the working of oneSignal, but the JSON string seems malformed. Currently missing a closing braces. Should it be `"{\"en\": \"English Message\"}"` ?

Comment: You can refer examples in postman https://gold-space-33090.postman.co/workspace/My-Workspace~be95e5cd-fd73-491a-802d-365281a88028/collection/9448291-4239c054-ecff-4af6-8ec8-d54487fdd1a1?ctx=documentation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure you format the JSON string correctly, e.g:

`{"en": "English Message", "es": "Spanish Message"}`

[Reference](https://documentation.onesignal.com/reference#section-content-language)

Answer (score 0):

Format the contents value with json_decode i.e you format this "{"en": "English Message" with json_decode e.g

```
$content = json_decode("{\"en\": \"English Message\");
```